# Exception in thread ... JComboBox, Jbutton and actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jframe, jcombobox

I am working on a school project and I want to add text from a text field through a button to a combo box. I save the `Object` with its attributes and then I add it to the combo box: in my case `cbbkateaus`.

When I run the app it doesn't add it to the combo box and I get this error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MtVwGui$2.actionPerformed(MtVwGui.java:119)
```

Followed by further `javax.swing...` errors but I think the former is the relevant one. I tried it with the `String` that I have in `//` but it leads to the same result.
(names of objects might be in German as an FYI)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
public class MtVwGui extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtHersteller;
    private JTextField txtModell;
    private JTextField txtBaujahr;
    private JTextField txtHubraum;
    private JTextField txtKategorien;
    private ArrayList<Kategorien> kategorienListe;
    private ArrayList<Motorraeder> motorraederListe;
    private Kategorien neueKategorie;
    private Motorraeder neuesMotorrad;
    private JComboBox cbbkateaus;
    

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MtVwGui frame = new MtVwGui();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MtVwGui() {
        kategorienListe= new ArrayList<Kategorien>();
        motorraederListe= new ArrayList<Motorraeder>();
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 888, 501);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        JLabel lbHersteller = new JLabel("Hersteller:");
        lbHersteller.setBounds(21, 95, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lbHersteller);
        
        txtHersteller = new JTextField();
        txtHersteller.setBounds(101, 92, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtHersteller);
        txtHersteller.setColumns(10);
        
        JLabel lbModell = new JLabel("Modell:");
        lbModell.setBounds(21, 128, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lbModell);
        
        txtModell = new JTextField();
        txtModell.setBounds(101, 123, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtModell);
        txtModell.setColumns(10);
        
        JLabel lbBaujahr = new JLabel("Baujahr:");
        lbBaujahr.setBounds(21, 153, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lbBaujahr);
        
        txtBaujahr = new JTextField();
        txtBaujahr.setBounds(101, 154, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtBaujahr);
        txtBaujahr.setColumns(10);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Hubraum:");
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(21, 190, 54, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
        
        txtHubraum = new JTextField();
        txtHubraum.setBounds(101, 187, 86, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtHubraum);
        txtHubraum.setColumns(10);
        
        JButton btnaddMtr = new JButton("Motorrad hinzuf\u00FCgen");
        btnaddMtr.setBounds(21, 259, 138, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnaddMtr);
        
        txtKategorien = new JTextField();
        txtKategorien.setBounds(446, 92, 100, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtKategorien);
        txtKategorien.setColumns(10);
        
        JButton btnaddKate = new JButton("Kategorie hinzuf\u00FCgen");
        btnaddKate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                
                neueKategorie = new Kategorien(txtKategorien.getText());
                
                //String addValue = txtKategorien.getText();
                kategorienListe.add(neueKategorie);

                cbbkateaus.addItem(neueKategorie);
                
                System.out.println("add Kategorie wurde gedrückt");
                System.out.println(neueKategorie.getBezeichnung());
                
            }
        });
        btnaddKate.setBounds(594, 91, 138, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnaddKate);
        
        JComboBox cbbkateaus = new JComboBox();
        
        cbbkateaus.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"none"}));
        cbbkateaus.setBounds(74, 215, 130, 23);
        contentPane.add(cbbkateaus);
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. mind the __M__ (nothing unrelated) and include the complete stacktrace formatted as code

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace you posted says it's on line 119, though I'm not sure which line that is. I pasted the entire code into a local editor and see only 117 lines.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MtVwGui$2.actionPerformed(MtVwGui.java:119)
```

The stack trace does show that it was thrown by `actionPerformed()`, which is your code. From there, we can infer that at least one of the following things in the code block below is `null` – "at least one" because, pedantically, there might be more than one `null` waiting for you to discover:

- `txtKategorien`
- `kategorienListe`
- `cbbkateaus`
- `neueKategorie`

```
btnaddKate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        
        neueKategorie = new Kategorien(txtKategorien.getText());
        
        //String addValue = txtKategorien.getText();
        kategorienListe.add(neueKategorie);

        cbbkateaus.addItem(neueKategorie);
        
        System.out.println("add Kategorie wurde gedrückt");
        System.out.println(neueKategorie.getBezeichnung());
        
    }
});
```

Using a debugger would be best, but adding these lines at the start of your `actionPerformed()` method would help you identify the problem:

```
System.out.println("txtKategorien: " + txtKategorien);
System.out.println("kategorienListe: " + kategorienListe);
System.out.println("cbbkateaus: " + cbbkateaus);
System.out.println("neueKategorie: " + neueKategorie);
```